Javascript Date function returning NaN in React Native
I am using the Javascript Date function in my application. I have an object message with this data
{
  "attachments": "[]", 
  "created_on": "2024-05-09 05:19:56.677747+00:00", 
  "message": "{\"room\":\"e08f1714-2558-4d73-b7f4-67dced45ace4\"}", 
  "msg_id": 3161, 
  "status": "completed", 
  "temp_id": null, 
  "user_id": 13064
}

I am using the Date function like this
const messageDate = message.created_on;
console.log(new Date(messageDate))

In my ReactJS app I am getting this output:
Fri May 24 2024 15:37:39 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)

but in my React Native app, I am getting
Date { NaN }

The behaviour is kind of strange I used the following function to get the same result
const normalizeDateString = (dateString) => {
  return dateString.replace(' ', 'T').replace(/\s+/g, '');
};

Why is the output of the same function different in two different places? This is quite strange. Can someone explain the root cause of this?

Observation and Root Cause:
Upon investigation of the old and latest APKs of the Android app, it was discovered that the Date function started returning NaN when provided with date strings lacking the T delimiter. This issue coincided with the recent disablement of the Hermes engine.
Different JavaScript engines like V8, JSC, and Hermes have their own standard library implementations, including for the Date object, which can lead to variations in behavior across platforms.
Conclusion:
The discrepancy in the behavior of the Date function appears to be directly linked to the use of the Hermes engine. Enabling Hermes resolves the issue while disabling it triggers the NaN result for date strings without the T delimiter.
To address this, a decision must be made regarding whether to re-enable Hermes or implement adjustments in the code to handle date strings differently when Hermes is disabled as per the use case.

The format (with out "T") is not ISO standard, and so different JS engines may deal differently with it. See docs: "T" is required - implementations are allowed to support other date formats when the input fails to match this format.

Where does this happen? On the device (mobile) or on your pc when developing in the Browser? Safari has some questionable Date parsing

So the created_on in your object is supposed to be the result of the normalizeDateString? How come, it hten contains a whitespace if you seem to remove all whitespaces from the string? And yes, something like 2024-01-0112:34:15 probably won't be accepted by any parser

@VincentMenzel—Safari parses the OP timestamp correctly, despite it not being supported by ECMA-262. Anything outside the supported formats is implementation dependent, all parsers have quirks in places.

@VincentMenzel This happens on mobile devices only, my web app on Chrome as well as Safari works fine without T in the date string.
